# Boot keeps dropping to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox after every upgrade

Tags: boot, nvidia, upgrade, ubuntu-mate, initramfs

I am on ubuntu mate 17.04. When i do

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then restart my computer, i get dropped to the busybox prompt. Then i do theses two steps

```
dumpe2fs /dev/sda5 | grep superblock
fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda5 -y
```

and then again restart the computer. It resumes normally. But every time i upgrade my machine same story. i have nvidia drivers installed. What is going wrong? Is there a solution other than not upgrading my machine?

Comment: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, have you installed a driver there that allows you to read/write to Ubuntu EXT4 partitions?

Comment: Yes i dual boot with windows 10. I installed DiskInternals-Linux-Reader software in windows to access Linux files from windows.

Comment: I have also installed EasyBCD and EaseUS PM in windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

*re: Do you dual-boot with Windows? If so, have you installed a driver there that allows you to read/write to Ubuntu EXT4 partitions?*

If `DiskInternals-Linux-Reader` software is like other similar Windows drivers, the result is the same... corrupted Ubuntu file systems.

Uninstall `DiskInternals-Linux-Reader` software, and `fsck` your Ubuntu partition once again, and I suspect that your problem will be solved.

If you really wish to share files between Windows and Ubuntu, create a new NTFS partition on your disk, and both can read/write to it.

Comment: I uninstalled that software and fscked but when i upgraded the boot initrafms must have been reset as i again got dropped to busybox prompt and had to recover using the two steps mentioned above. Is the distro at fault? Because i uninstalled nvidia drivers also.  And i have worked with other linux distros and never come across this problem.

Comment: I assume that you're doing `fsck` at the Additional Options/Root Access GRUB menu, yes? What happens if you just `fsck -f /` or `fsck -f /dev/sda5`... do you get a superblock error? Lets try and create a new initramfs for you... boot up fully, and in `terminal` do `sudo update-initramfs -c -k "$(uname -r)"`, then reboot.

Comment: @user_1_1_1 ps: do you have a SSD?

Comment: I am doing `fsck` at busybox prompt only:  `fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda5 -y`. Let me try your suggestions and get back to you.